# Postfix deny all relay domain destinations except for relay_domains

Tags: email, postfix

Im running Debian 11 with Postfix 3.5.17 and I'm having trouble restricting the domains that clients can relay mail to (mail from submission).

I've configured relay_domains to only be the specific domains I want mail relayed to, but if I send a test message to domain.com, the logs show its connecting to it, despite it not being in relay_domains.

It seems relay_domains is not actually denying anything right now, is there an extra config option or restriction needed for this to take affect?

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
default_destination_rate_delay = 5s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 550
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 3h
minimal_backoff_time = 180s
mydestination = localhost
mydomain = localmail.com
myhostname = localmail.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 172.20.0.0/16 10.10.0.0/16 192.168.0.0/16
myorigin = $mydomain
non_fqdn_reject_code = 550
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = protonmail.com, protonmail.ch, mail.protonmail.ch, mailsec.protonmail.ch
relayhost =
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_helo_timeout = 15s
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 15s
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 10
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_limit = 40
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unlisted_recipient, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_timeout = 30s
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mailtls-selfsigned.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mailtls-selfsigned.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_use_tls = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of restrictions matters, the first matching rule wins.

Because you have `permit_mynetworks` before any other restrictions, that allows hosts on your local networks to relay to anywhere.  Similarly, you have `permit_sasl_authenticated` as the second restriction, which allows authenticated clients to relay to any domain.

If you don't want that, put `reject_unauth_destination` **before** `permit_mynetworks` and `permit_sasl_authenticated`.

From `man 5 postconf`:

> `reject_unauth_destination`
>
> Reject the request unless one of the following is true:
>
> - Postfix is a mail forwarder: the resolved RCPT TO domain matches
>   `$relay_domains` or a subdomain thereof, and contains no sender-specified
>   routing (user@elsewhere@domain),
> - Postfix is the final destination: the resolved RCPT TO domain
>   matches `$mydestination`, `$inet_interfaces`, `$proxy_interfaces`,
>   `$virtual_alias_domains`, or `$virtual_mailbox_domains`, and contains no
>   sender-specified routing (user@elsewhere@domain).
>
> The `relay_domains_reject_code` parameter specifies the response code for
> rejected requests (default: 554).

Comment: Thanks! Is mynetworks interchangeable with sasl_authenticated? Like if a server successfully authenticates but is not in mynetworks, are they allowed to submit/relay mail?

Comment: They're separate checks. And the order of checks is important.  e.g. if you have `permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination` the hosts in mynetworks AND those who authenticate via sasl can relay to anywhere....but if you have `permit_myneworks, reject_unauth_destination, permit_sasl_authenticated` then hosts in mynetworks can relay to anywhere, while sasl authenticated hosts can only relay to $relay_domains.  The exact rules you use are important (e.g. compare `permit_auth_destination` and `reject_unauth_destination`) **AND** the **order** of rules is important.